# how to set phpdbg colours

Tags: php, phpdbg

I'm using phpdbg and I see that you can change the colour of errors and output.  This would be very useful as it is not so easy to read when it is all just in one colour.

But I can't get it to work.  Am I doing it wrong or is it known not to be working on windows 8.1?

This is what I have tried:

```
S C on
set color prompt white-bold
S c error red-bold
```

just as suggested in the help.  I get the following message on all three of the above lines:

```
[No set command selected!]
```

I'm using php 5.6.7 x86 on windows 8.1

I have tried setting the prompt eg.`set p >` and that works, so set is recognized.  I have also tried entering the command in full eg.`set colors on` but it makes no difference.

Comment: It's a Windows problem… it doesn't display colors. Go to *nix and it'll magically work ;-)

Comment: unfortunately that's not an option

Comment: Then you're out of luck. the Windows version of phpdbg doesn't compile colors at all because they just don't work there (that's why you get "No set command selected!").